# I am getting Error in Spring Boot Application: Description: required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cache.CacheManager' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am getting CacheManager error.

> Error Message: required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cache.CacheManager' that could not be found.

> Action : Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cache.CacheManager' in your configuration.

Comment: so, you should "consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cache.CacheManager' in your configuration"

Comment: Annotate your class with `@EnableCaching` annotation